# How to include libxml++ library, correctly?

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, linker-flags

I would like to compile this code in windows 7: ([this](http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2013/02/parsing-html-with-c/))

```
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    xmlpp::DomParser doc;
    // 'response' contains your HTML
    doc.parse_memory(CleanHTML(html));

    xmlpp::Document* document = doc.get_document();
    xmlpp::Element* root = document->get_root_node();

    xmlpp::NodeSet elemns = root->find("descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'some_id']");
    std::cout << elemns[0]->get_line() << std::endl;
    std::cout << elemns.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Code::Blocks, but it gives me errors:

```
undefined reference to `xmlpp::DomParser::DomParser()'
undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(std::string const&)'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::DomParser::parse_memory(Glib::ustring const&)'
undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::DomParser::get_document()'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::Document::get_root_node() const'
undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::find(Glib::ustring const&) const'
undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::Node::get_line() const'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::DomParser::~DomParser()'
undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
undefined reference to `xmlpp::DomParser::~DomParser()'
```

So, I thought that I did not linked my librarys correctly; I go in ->project->build options->compiler settings->other options : and I added =>

- IC:/gdkdir/include/glib-2.0
- IC:/gdkdir/lib/glib-2.0/include
- IC:/gdkdir/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl
- IC:/gdkdir/include/gtk-3.0
- IC:/gdkdir/include/cairo
- IC:/gdkdir/include/pango-1.0
- IC:/gdkdir/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
- IC:/gdkdir/include/libpng15
- IC:/gdkdir/include/pixman-1
- IC:/gdkdir/include
- IC:/gdkdir/include/freetype2

Helped with [this](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/) I downloaded the librarys => libxml2 and glibmm2.4 and I included them.

And it still gives me the same errors!

Please help me.

UPDATE 17/06 : I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642238/issue-linking-libxml-and-glib-libraries-with-codeblocks-ide-for-c-windows?rq=1) but it still gives me the same errors!

UPDATE 18/06 : That's what I did:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you use -llibxml flag while compiling ?

Comment: in the "other-options" of code:blokcs ? , in it i added -LC:\lib\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib -llibxml2

Comment: Isn't it -lxml2 or, probably, -lxml2++?

Comment: i included both , but still same errors

Comment: Including != linking. You need to tell the linker where the libraries live (`/lib/`), not where the headers live (`/include/`).

Comment: ?? i don't get it :.. in the "linker settings" i put the "/lib/" and in the "search directorys" i put "/include/"